# Error: Cannot encode type ([object Undefined]) to a Firestore Value

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

i want to add user details in firestore when new user signs up but i m getting this error in console about "Undefined object"

function:

```
  exports.storeUserData = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event =>{
    const user = event.data;
     var db_uid_user = db_firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
        'name' : user.displayName,
        'email': user.email,
        'phoneNumber': user.phoneNumber,
        'photoUrl': user.photoURL

    });

     console.log('User Add (uid)',user.uid);

});
```

ERROR:

```
 Error: Cannot encode type ([object Undefined]) to a Firestore Value
    at Function.encodeValue (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/document.js:658:11)
    at Function.encodeFields (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/document.js:530:36)
    at WriteBatch.set (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/write-batch.js:254:35)
    at DocumentReference.set (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/reference.js:416:8)
    at exports.storeUserData.functions.auth.user.onCreate.event (/user_code/index.js:15:71)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:59:27)
    at next (native)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
    at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:53:36)
```

Answer (score 2):

So, i forgot that details that user object contain is limited with what kind of Auth your using.

For example: 
if you are using Email and password , your user object will have only email,password,uid.

hence

```
     'name' : user.displayName,        //invalid undefined object 
    'email': user.email,               //valid
    'phoneNumber': user.phoneNumber,   //invalid
    'photoUrl': user.photoURL          //invalid
```